# How can I map arbitrary group elements to unique integers without using Hash functions?

Tags: hash

Let's say, I have a group $G$ of large prime order $p$. A set $S$ consists of $n$ random elements chosen from $G$. Without using a collision resistant hash function $H$, how can I map elements of $G$ to unique elements in $Z_p$?

I thought about it before posting here. But, finding discrete logarithm for an arbitrary group is hard, right? In theory, it'd satisfy the requirement of collision resistance, but inefficient.

I don't really know the structure of the group beforehand. What I am essentially trying to do is, I am trying to figure out a generic means to map public key ($PK$) of a Public Key Encryption system to $z \in Z_p$, such that a third party can be convinced about the co-relation between the $PK$ and $z$ without revealing $PK$ but $z$ and some form of proof-of-knowledge. Hash functions, due it inherent nature of pre-image resistance, seems unsuitable.

Comment: If you can find a non-identity element and efficiently compute discrete logarithms, then you can use Dennis's suggestion. $\:$ If $S$ is determined before (or independently of) the map, then you can just use a [universal hash family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing). $\:$ If neither of those hold, then I'm pretty sure it depends on the group $G$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I have updated the original post to make it clearer. Please go it through once more.

Comment: Why does the ring's ($Z_p$'s) size need to be the same as $G$'s? $\;$

Comment: It needn't be, but will that help?

Comment: Sorry, but I remain confused. 1. Why are you keeping the *public* key secret? 2. What *does* the third party know? What exactly is it supposed to be able to verify?

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock : $\:$ Yes, since it would let $p$ be bigger than all of the group elements. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @Ricky Demer How can I translate the group elements to $Z_p$ elements in that case?

Comment: You would use [bit padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Bit_padding) so that padded group elements all have the same length, let $p$ be bigger than 2 to that length, and map each group element to the integer represented by the result of padding the group element. $\;$

Comment: @Dennis 1. This is in connection to Ring signature where the verifier need to know that the message has been signed by someone belonging to that ring but the signer's identity need to be unrevealed.

2. The third-party will be sent a commitments to both $PK$ and $z$.

3. It is supposed to verify that $z$ is, indeed, derived from $PK$.

Comment: @Ricky Demer As I explained to Dennis in the comment just above, my idea is to apply these ideas in a ring signature scheme. The third-party/verifier will be sent the commitments to $PK$ and $z$ to verify the co-relation between these two. If I use bit-padding as you told, can this claim(i.e. $PK$ and $z$ being derived co-relate) be proved to the verifier without divulging any other secret?

Comment: I'm not particularly knowledgeable about ring signatures, but couldn't you just release *all* public keys without disclosing which belongs to whom?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, the set of all public keys or the ring information is public, but not the ownership of the keys. Any member of the ring can sign on behalf of the ring without disclosing his identity.

Comment: So, verification of a signature should just consist in trying all public keys, correct?

Comment: Actually I was a bit wrong. The verifier knows which public is owned by whom, i.e. the ownership. The scheme which I am going through, there they have shared a commitment to signer's public key, thus making it impossible to trace it back.

Comment: How are you representing elements G?  Any group of prime order is isomorphic to $Z_p$ so you can just use that isomorphism.

Comment: Depending on the underlying PKE scheme, group elements are represented. How can I derive such a homomorphism?

Comment: The method given in Dennis's answer is the only way for an arbitrary group, but note that you get a different mapping depending on which generator you pick.  I was thinking that if you knew more about $G$ or how an element of $g$ was represented there might be an integer 0 <= i < p that each element would naturally map to.  But it sounds like you're trying to do this without knowing anything about $G$?  You might need to rethink that requirement if you want this to be practical.

Comment: Any mapping which ignores the group structure will be based solely on element representation and would probably not be usable in a ZKP. Also, why invent a new ring signature scheme rather than using an [existing one](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=ring+signature)?

Answer (score 1):

The order of every element $g$ of a group $G$ divides the order of the group ($p$).

Since $p$ is prime, every $g\in G$ has order $1$ or $p$. Only the identity element $e$ satisfies the first case, so every $g\in G\setminus\{e\}$ is a generator of $G$, i.e., $$G = \{g^0,g^1,g^2,\cdots,g^{p-1}\}.$$

This allows defining a bijection $$\begin{array}{cccc}\varphi:&\mathbb Z_p&\rightarrow& G\\&n&\mapsto&g^n\end{array}.$$

If you can find $\varphi^{-1}$, you're done.

Comment: Note that finding $\varphi^{-1}$ might be infeasible in some cases. It would help to know which group you're trying to map to $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: I have updated the original post to make it clearer. Please go it through once more.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ does not have order $p$, unless you use the addition as group operation. The multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ has order $p-1$.

Comment: @tylo: The order of a finite group equals its number of elements, so for all valid group operations $*_1$ and $*_2$, $(\mathbb Z_p,*_1)$ and $(\mathbb Z^*_p,*_2)$ have orders $p$ and $p-1$, respectively. Since $\mathbb Z_p\neq\mathbb Z^*_p$, I'm not sure what your example is supposed to prove.

Comment: @tylo: I use multiplicative notion for the group $G$, yes. $\mathbb Z_p$ is a simple set here. No group operation required.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with an [article in a wiki about group theory](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_of_prime_order). That one states, that it is automatically cyclic and it is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_p,+)$. Formally speaking, it is abelian, cyclic, nilpotent, and of course finite.

That means actually you know a *lot* about the group structure ahead of time. Because it is already fully determined with a variable $p$.

That means, you actually don't need to anything, because the isomorphism into $(\mathbb{Z}_p,+)$ does everything for you. If you want to add some more flavor, you can choose a generator other than the usual $1$ for the additive group, or since you don't need the structure preserving property, just choose any bijective function, e.g. a polynomial with a degree coprime to $p-1$.